# Laravel: Delete migration before migrate:reset

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I am trying to reset all tables in my database using following command:

**php artisan migrate:reset**
Unfortunately I get this error:
Fatal error:  Class 'AddAgeToPostsTables' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gitprojects\laravel

[image]

Before try to reset the tables I deleted a migration. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: take a screenshot of ur migration folder and share it here

Comment: Hi, I added a screenshort.

Comment: the code inside of it also pls

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Xamp, you should have access to PhpMyAdmin. Go find the database associated with your Laravel app, and then manually delete every table (but not the database itself). Then, run `php artisan migrate`. Since you deleted your `migrations` table, Laravel will re-run all of the `up` migrations. That should solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling a `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Hi I tried to call composer dump-autoload and php artisan optimize. But I have the same problem.

Comment: nop that's only valid for seedclass i guess, i bet it's a naming issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to rollback the steps

**php artisan migrate:rollback**

And then migrate

**php artisan migrate**

Else manual delete the migration and tables from the db

Answer (score 0):

check your **drop()** function  in your migration file. Probably you left it blank.

Answer (score 0):

delete the migration table from database.

then use

php artisan migrate:install

php artisan migrate